# numpy data sounds different than original sound_file.wav file

Tags: python-3.x, audio-processing

```
import wave
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, Audio

#sound 1 
with wave.open('sound_file.wav', 'rb') as wf:
  signal = np.frombuffer(wf.readframes(nframes = wf.getnframes()), 'int' + str(int(16 * wf.getsampwidth())))
  display(Audio(data = signal, rate = wf.getframerate()))

#sound2
display(Audio('sound_file.wav'))
```

here the sound1 sounds different than sound2 so can anyone tell me what happens there. 
As well as please state some usual practices of sound preprocessing that must be done after getting an np array from a sound file.

Comment: In which way does it sound different? Volume? Pitch? Any distortion?

Comment: Btw, I would highly recommend using the soundfile library for this. https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: there was a distortion. Instead of converting to NumPy array if you pass the bitstring directly then also it sounds smooth.  I later used librosa.load and it worked.